# Snowflake - How to Multi Line Comment

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a shortcut for multi line commenting out? A.k.a. commenting blocks of SQL at a time via a shortcut or menu option?

Answer (score 3):

You have to highlight the rows you want to comment out and then press `Cmd (Mac) or Crtl (Windows) + /`

See here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html

Comment: I tried doing this.

I am on a windows machine.

Comment: Hold down CTRL and while doing so, hold the Windows button, and then hit the "/" button?

Comment: is that my understanding? is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, it's `CTRL /`. So hold down `CTRL` and then press `/`.

Comment: Exactly. CTRL and then - while CTRL is still pressed - you press /.

Comment: does typing `/*` at the start and `*/` at the end enough?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's something like multi-line comment in snowflake. Even on the community page: [page](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-comment-or-uncomment-multiple-lines-in-the-sql-worksheet) there's just the shortcut for a single line comment while having the whole thing highlighted, which is:

Press **CMD + / (Mac)** or **CTRL + / (Windows)** again.  The comments are removed from the highlighted lines.